# How can I compare the Image of an ImageButton to a drawable?

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-drawable, imagebutton

I want a certain action to be done if the image of my ImageButton `button` is equal to a drawable. Like this:

```
if (button.getBackground().getConstantState()==getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mydrawable).getConstantState())
{
     //perform action//
}
```

But if I do so, `getDrawable` gets red underline and I don't know why?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: surely there's some logic which is setting your buttons drawable to this value, right ? why not add checks there instead of checking which resources is attached ?

Comment: what do you mean with checks? I have a ImageButton whose Image can be chosen by the user. If a certain Image is chosen on that ImageButton, I want a specific action that only happens when exactly that Image is set...

Comment: so when a user chose an image, just use a custom variable to keep which one he chose and compare what you need to this variable. Much better than comparing drawable.

Comment: that's actually better, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First

```
ImageButton temp =  findViewById(R.id.myImagebtn);
Bitmap imageBtm = ((BitmapDrawable)temp.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.apple);
Bitmap appleBtm = ((BitmapDrawable) myDrawable).getBitmap();
```

second

```
if(imageBtm.sameAs(appleBtm))
{
Log.i("Bitmap compare", "equal");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

getConstantState() doesn't always work.

You could compare if they are equal with their :

- width x height
- pixels
- bytes

Comment: Unfortunately I only have pictures which same size, both in pixels and bytes. Isn't there any other function I could use? Somehow it has to be possible to compare id´s or something like that...